# What are the most extreme chemicals?

Tags: reference-request, elements

*Some chemicals certainly have extraordinary properties. One can consider them extreme in a sense, that they are the prime example for a concept, or they achieve the highest or lowest values in a certain area.*

This Q&A attempts to compile a list of questions asked on this network, which have a background related to such extreme values or properties. we decided to add such a list because it is a popular search term.

It is a community effort, hence everybody with more than 100 reputation points can edit the answer. If you think something is missing in this list, just go ahead and add it. This post will be locked to prevent adding new answers, though. The corresponding discussion can be found on [meta.chemistry.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/most-extreme-chemicals). If you think there are some obvious points missing here, please go there and open a discussion.

Comment: Define "extreme"

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107   *Extreme* means "the highest or lowest measure/value for some particular physical or chemical characteristic."

Comment: @Java see the [meta](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/most-extreme-chemicals) on this. This was intended to be created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- [Densest gas](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16439/5354)
- [Densest element](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/21662/5354)
- [Greatest range between melting and boiling temperature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33553/5354)
- [Highest melting point](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15141/5354)
- [Lowest solubility product constant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27842/5354)
- Most dangerous: [Is there any substance that's a 4-4-4 on the NFPA diamond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/is-there-any-substance-thats-a-4-4-4-on-the-nfpa-diamond). But also, don't forget that the NPFA diamond doesn't even classify ClF<sub>3</sub> as flammable (though everything else is flammable in it) and by any criterion it is far more dangerous than the other compounds in those answers)
- [Strongest acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/17124/5354)
- [Strongest organic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/whats-the-strongest-known-organic-acid)
- [Strongest reducing agent](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28568/5354)

Good external lists:

- [Most extreme compounds known to man](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=18274).